# Azure apps with WebRTC

Tags: azure, webrtc

Is it possible to get an app that uses WebRTC (acting like a "regular client", since WebRTC is a P2P protocol) to work as an Azure App?

It seems that Azure Apps are too restrictive with their ports for WebRTC to work as intended.

Mostly I ask because such an application has already been developed and tested locally, but silently fails when ported to an Azure App. The library used for WebRTC communications (IceLink) gets to the point where it should decide if the link to a peer is up or not, but just stops there and doesn't call the expected callback, nor issue an error, log something, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The creators of the library I'm using were able to answer this:

> You can run on Azure, but you have to use a dedicated VM. The cloud/role/app offering does not support the ports/protocols required for P2P communications.

http://support.frozenmountain.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203604033-IceLink-application-on-an-Azure-App#answer-205871726